# How to mock out an assignment resulting from a method chain in Rspec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, rspec

I am working on retroactively testing a payment gateway integration class. There is method `purchase`, within which `payment_method` is assigned via the following code:

```
payment_method = order.purchaser.payment_methods.build(
                 transaction.payment_method.field_hash
                 .select { |k, _| valid_payment_method_params.include?(k) }
                 .merge(type: transaction.payment_details.payment_type.camelize)
                 )
```

Later on in `purchase`, `payment_method` is used in some conditional statements to get some return values.

I need to ensure payment_method has a certain value. My first instinct is to somehow mock out the return value. E.g. -

```
allow(:payment_method).to be(my_value)
```

That's pseudo code, though, and I've been unable to find its equivalent in the Relish docs. This is not the first time I've come up again this kind of situation, so I believe I'm missing something fundamental or apparent and would love some insight.

How can I mock out this assignment and ensure that `payment_method` is what I want it to be?

Answer (score 0):

So after discussing this in a different forum I've learned that mocks can only target method calls and not local variables. Therefore, the solution I landed upon was to extract the right side of that assignment to its own method, and then mock out that method. For example:

```
def new_method_with_extracted_logic(order)
  order.purchaser.payment_methods.build(
             transaction.payment_method.field_hash
             .select { |k, _| valid_payment_method_params.include?(k) }
             .merge(type: transaction.payment_details.payment_type.camelize)
             )
end
```

Then:

```
allow(self).to receive(:new_method_with_extracted_logic).with(:order)and_return(object_i_want)
```